# Is any closed set a derived set?

Tags: general-topology

Is any closed set a derived set :

- in the real line ;
- in a finite dimensional vector space ;
- in an infinite dimensional vector space ?

  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ be a closed set. 
Let $D=A\setminus A'$. Then the points $x\in D$ are isolated points of $A$, i.e. there exists $r(x)>0$ such that $B(x,r(x))\cap A=\{x\}$.
Let $$C=A\cup \{\,x+\tfrac{r(x)}{n+2}:x\in A\setminus A', n\in\mathbb N\,\}.$$
Note that for $x\in A\setminus A'$, we have $B(x,r(x))\cap C=\{\,x+\frac{r(x)}{n+2}:n\in\mathbb N\,\}$.

**Claim.** The closed set $A$ is the derived set $C'$.

*Proof.* First we see that $A\subseteq C'$: Let $a\in A$. If $a\in A'$ we are done because $A'\subseteq C'$. So assume $a\in A'\setminus A$. Then the sequence $a+\frac{r(a)}{n+2}$ converges to $a$, showing $a\in C'$.

Remains to show that $C'\subseteq A$: Let $c\in C'$, say $c_k\to c$ with pairwise distinct $c_k\in C$. If $c_k\in A$ for infinitely many $k$, then $c$ is a limit point of $A$, hence in $A$ and we are done. Hence $c_k\in A$ only for finitely many $k$, and wlog. $c_k\notin A$ for all $k$. Then $c_k=a_k+\frac{r(a_k)}{n_k+2}$ with $a_k\in A\setminus A'$, $n_k\in\mathbb N$.
Let  $s=\liminf\{\,r(a_k):k\in\mathbb N\,\}$. If $s=0$, then a subsequence of the $r(a_k)$ converges to $0$, hence the corresponding $a_k$ converge to $c$, which implies $c\in A'$. Assume therefore that $s>0$.
We have $|c_k-c|<\frac s{12}$ for almost all $k$ and we have $r(a_k)>\frac12 s$ for infinitely many $k$, hence for infinitely many $k$, we have
$$|a_k-c|\le |a_k-c_k|+|c_k-c|< \frac{r(a_k)}{3}+\frac s{12}<\frac12r(a_k).$$
Witin this subsequence, we conclude that $$|a_{k_1}-a_{k_2}|\le |a_{k_1}-c|+|a_{k_2}-c|< \frac{r(a_{k_1})+r(a_{k_2})}{2}\le \max\{r(a_{k_1}),r(a_{k_2})\}$$ and hence $a_{k_1}=a_{k_2}$.
Thus there exists $a\in A\setminus A'$ such that $c_k=a+\frac{r(a)}{n_k+2}$ and all $n_k$ must be distinct. This implies $c=a\in A$. $_\square$

The proof can be generalized at least to metric spaces $X$ without isolated points: All we need is a generalization of $x+\frac{r(x)}{n+2}$, that is for each isoloated point $x$ of $A$, we can pick a countable subset of a "private" neighbourhood of $x$ that has $x$ as limit point.