# Every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a derived set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can I show that given a closed subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, there is some set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A= B'$, where $B'$ denotes the derived set of $B$? I feel as though this should be simple, so perhaps I am missing something...

Comment: If $A_x=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty\left(x-1/i\right)$,how about considering $B=\bigcup\limits_{x \in A }A_x$?I am not sure...I think it might work

Comment: If the $A$is a closed interval or a finite union of closed intervals then $B=A$. If it contains no interval then maybe you can use this idea - it should be totally discontinuous and hence a discrete space. So for every point in $A$ consider a sequence converging to it. The unioin of all such sequences should give a $B$. But I'm not entirely sure of the last line.

Comment: @Rise It's not true that closed sets not containing intervals are discrete - e.g. the Cantor set.

Comment: I think it is duplicate question.answer is given at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990157/is-any-closed-set-a-derived-set

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose $A$ into $A=L\cup I$ where $L=\{\text{$x\in A$|$x$ is a limit point of $A$}\}$ and $I=\{\text{$x\in A$|$x$ is an isolated point of $A$}\}$.

For each $x\in I$, there exist $r_x>0$ such that $B(x,r_x)$ contains no other points of $A$. Let 
$$S_x=\{x,x+\frac{r_x}2,x+\frac{r_x}3,... \}$$
Observe that by letting
$
S=\bigcup_{x\in I}S_x
$
, $S'=I$ (Prove this!). By construction $S$ is disjoint from $L$. Letting
$$ B=L\cup S$$
we can see that $B'=A$, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this: Since $A$ is closed, we know that $A'\subseteq A$. So, intuitively, we want $B$ to be $A$ together with "extra stuff," $E$. This extra stuff should have two properties:

- Every point of $A\setminus A'$ is a limit of points in $E$, but
- no point not in $A$ is a limit of points in $E\cup A$.

If we can find such an $E$, then $B=A\cup E$ will be as desired.

---

So our first question is:

> What does $A\setminus A'$ look like?

As it turns out, there's a lot we can say about this set; but for now, we just need:

- The points in $A\setminus A'$ are (strongly) isolated: we may associate intervals $I_x$ to each $x\in A\setminus A'$ such that $I_x\cap A=\{x\}$ and $I_x\cap I_y=\emptyset$ for $x\not=y$.

EXERCISE 1: Prove that. (It may be helpful to first show that $A\setminus A'$ is countable . . . )

EXERCISE 2: For each $x\in A\setminus A'$, let $I_x$ be such an open interval. Since $I_x$ is open, we can find a sequence of points $x_0<x_1<x_2< . . . $, $x_i\in I_x$, with $\lim x_i=x$. Let $E=\{x_i: x\in A\setminus A'\}$. Show that $(E\cup A)'=A$.